# Gradle Sync Issues Activity end tag

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.myapplication3">

application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true>
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".ChooseLoginRegistrationActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >

    <activity android:name = "ChooseLoginRegistrationActivity">
        "</intent-filter>"
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <intent-filter>
        </intent-filter>"</activity>".
            "</application>".

</manifest>=======<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<application>
    "</activity>" android:name="com.example.myapplication3.RegistrationActivity">"</activity>"
</application>
```

Comment: Gradle Sync Issues Activity must be terminated by matching end tag. I don't know what to do to resolve the issue. My first app

Comment: Its a bit hard to understand what you are asking - can you please clarify the question? This way, we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted your Manifest.

```
<application

android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".ChooseLoginRegistrationActivity"></activity>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" >

<activity android:name = "ChooseLoginRegistrationActivity">
        <intent-filter>    
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>

</application>
```

In Line 10, there's two ChooseLoginRegistrationActivity and MainActivity doesn't have `</activity>`.

So, I think below is correct in your case.

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".ChooseLoginRegistrationActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```